# Decision boundary in Logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, python, sigmoid-curve

According to me in logistic regression, we just try to get a line (polynomial)
and then based on which side the point is from that line the sigmoid gives ans>=0.5 or <0.5,
which we then interpret as 1 (if ans>=0.5) and 0 if (ans < 0.5).
Here is a simple plot what I mean.

[image]

This is just a random line not a line predicted by any logistic regression model.
Here we are only having one feature i.e., x. y is the output(0 or 1).
The decision boundary here is x = -3 and x = 3.

So when we have 1 feature we try to get a good line to predict the values.

What if we have 2 features we try to get a plane instead?

This is a 3-d plot of a normal sigmoid.

[image]

So if we have 2 features say x and y.
For these we are trying to get a plane in z axis which separate the points? which is in turn the decision boundary.
I am really confused.? Is this what we are doing?

If yes, can someone plot a 3d plot (of sigmoid/decision boundary) for a circle.
For eg:

[image]

This is also a random plot. Suppose that our points are like this and our model has given us a circle to differentiate between 0 and 1. So can anyone plot a decision boundary of something like this (which is is 3-D).

Comment: For a 3D analogue of your circle, wouldn’t it just be points of one color inside a sphere and points of another color outside? Such a visualization might prove frustrating, but the idea makes sense, right? I do, however, see that as separate from your question about the sigmoid function, hence my answer not addressing it.

Comment: Assume that on a table the points/marbles are distributes as show in the circle(plot above). now lets assume the red marbles are y=1 and blue one's are 0. Now to make this to 3-D, lift the red points in the air. as table top will be indicating 0 and the red one's lifted in air means 1. So I think cylinder or something like that should be the actual thing in 3-D. sphere can also be a valid here.

Comment: Sphere, cylinder, cone, wilting wizard’s hat…all seem plausible in three dimensions, though only a sphere strikes me as analogous to a circle in the plane. // The business about decision boundaries seems rather unrelated to the question about the sigmoid function and perhaps should be posted as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

The sigmoid function takes the linear predictor of the logistic regression and bends it into a range, $[0,1]$, that can interpreted as a probability. The linear predictor can take any real number, which is fine if we think about the log-odds. However, for valid probability values, the must be a transformation to restrict outputs to $[0,1]$.

Any business about a decision boundary is separate from the sigmoid function. In fact, it is totally reasonable to do a decision boundary in terms of log-odds and skip the sigmoid function altogether. Just evaluate if the prediction has positive or negative log-odds, and classify accordingly. This is equivalent to the decision rule in the OP, and it is a worthwhile exercise to consider why.

As always, hard classifications need not be made, since a logistic regression explicitly predicts probability values that can be valuable on their own without considering hard classifications (at least not initially). Our Stephen Kolassa’s answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/247274) gets into some of that.

Comment: If we have a circle as a decision boundary (as shown in the post). Does that mean in actual 3rd dimension the plan is a cylinder or something like that?